# Will a Perl script still run after I log out of my user account?

Tags: terminal, user-account

I have started a Perl script from the terminal that runs in the background:

```
>perl myScript.pl &
```

If I logout, will it stop my script from running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is dead easy to test.  Write a perl script that appends the date to a file every minute, and run it in the background.  Log out, wait 5 minutes, log in, check for 5 entries corresponding to the times you are logged out. To get it working in future (too late if it's already running) use nohup as explained in another answer. You can background a foreground script after you start it (CTRL-Z) but you can only nohup it at execution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the thing is my script has been running for a long time and I did not want to stop to test it.  I had no idea it was going to run this long but I just ran some calculations and this looks to be about a 90hr job!

Comment: If you have any doubt, then stick to a) password protected screensaver rather than logging out if security is the issue, or b) turn on fast user switching if someone else needing to use the computer is the issue - neither of these will affect it.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @stuffe's answer, if you are logged in via `ssh` and run your command, it will die when you close the connection.  So, if you were at home and `ssh`'ed into your office workstation and executed your `perl myScript.pl &` command, it would die when you `exit`'ed from the `ssh` connection.

To avoid this problem, you'll want to use the `nohup` command, which dates back to the teletype days and stands for "no hangup" --- essentially it causes the command to ignore the POSIX HUP (hangup) signal.  It is used as:

```
nohup perl myScript.pl &
```

This will keep running on your office workstation even after you have disconnected/logged out from your home machine.

Comment: indeed, nohup is the answer!

Comment: This is great. Thank you. After executing exactly as described, I get the message "nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'" as expected, **but I don't see a Unix prompt**. Based on your answer, it probably doesn't matter if connection is lost/closed. But say if I want to use the same command line window to do other things,  is there a way to let the command line prompt to come up?

Comment: I think I figured it out: I typed in "bg" to let run in the background. To check the status, I typed in "jobs".